# Freeform: Accessing form values to create subject

Tags: plugin-freeform

I'm trying to make specific subjects and submission titles so that it's easier to understand what kind of email we just received or what kind of submission it is in the Freeform Submissions page. I'm trying to access form values and entry variables to be used in these subjects and titles.

I've just tried to use `form.fullName` (`fullName` being a form field) into my auto-generated Submission Title (under Form Settings tab in composer), but received this error after hitting submit on the front-end:

> Neither the property "fullName" nor one of the methods "fullName()",
>   "getfullName()"/"isfullName()" or "__call()" exist and have public
>   access in class "Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Form"

While we're at it, is it also possible to get the entry title that the form has been injected into as a value to be used as well?

Ideally I'm looking for the naming convention: [`form.name`] `entry.title` - `form.fullName`

If perhaps an entry variable is not present, then it should gracefully degrade.